# Keeping track of purchase counts using a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am creating a trigger whenever a purchase event gets inserted or updated in the PurchaseEvent table below.

The actual product count (completed purchases) is currently not tracked in a table, it is dynamically calculated each time by performing a SUM on the PurchaseEvent table like:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM PurchaseEvent WHERE ProductID = @ProductID and PurchaseStatus = 'COMPLETED'
```

Below is the main PurchaseEvent table and the new table I just created:

```
PurchaseEvent
- PurchaseEventID
- ProductID
- Quantity
- PurchaseStatus ( COMPLETED, CANCELLED)

ProductCount
- ProductID
- ProductCount
```

I am creating a trigger to handle the insert or update events.

A row can be updated to change the PurchaseStatus.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateProductCount
  ON PurchaseEvent
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON


  // TODO

END
```

Since a trigger can be run for a single record or multiple, what is the best way to handle this?

I was thinking:

```
UPDATE pc
  SET rc.PurchaseCount = rc.PurchaseCount + SUM(i.ProductID)
FROM PurchaseCount pc
  INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.ProductID = pc.ProductID
WHERE i.PurchaseStatus = 'COMPLETED'
```

But then I have to somehow handle the `CANCELLED` records also?

Is it possible to just increment/decrement the PurchaseCount table or is the only
way to do this accurately is to SUM the original table each and every time a record is updated/inserted? (and just ignore the records in the INSERTED table)

Comment: Storing aggregated values generally is a bad idea, in my opinion. Values can become de-synced and then wrong, You're better off with the `VIEW` you already have.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu this is not a great idea. But if you insist on storing aggregated data using triggers you absolutely MUST have a delete trigger. Even if there is no way currently in the application to delete it may in the future. Or some rows get deleted as a result of a data cleanup because of a bug and your totals are out of whack.

Comment: If you continue with the trigger concept you would likely want to use a case expression. This way you can increment the count when completed, otherwise subtract. Still this is slipper slope that I wouldn't use.  rc.PurchaseCount * case when i.PurchaseStatus = 'COMPLETED' then 1 else -1 end

Comment: @Larnu Experiencing a performance issue b/c calculating the counts is too slow.  A view won't help with performance right?

Comment: Do you have the required indexes for good performance?

Comment: As for the trigger, should you decide to go that way, you can do it either way, i.e. calculate the value from scratch *OR* calculate the adjustment and adjust the final value. Once they work they are mostly fine, but a tiny mistake and you've got crap data.

Comment: I'd start looking at performance tuning the `VIEW` first then. Or, if you want a parametrise version, look at an inline TVF.